# Azure DevOps - how to reference Pipeline variables in pom file's build finalName?

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build a Java application with maven 3.6.1 via Azure Pipelines.

How can I reference predefined variables that are exposed by the pipeline in my build > finalName in my POM file?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

I am trying something like this but it is not resolving:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${env.Build.BuildNumber}</finalName>
```

For my pipeline, I am using ubuntu-latest image when doing the build.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I inject build version into pom.xml using TFS on UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205633/how-do-i-inject-build-version-into-pom-xml-using-tfs-on-ui)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by adding a BUILD_NUMBER variable to azure-pipelines.yml:

```
variables:
  MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.m2/repository
  MAVEN_OPTS: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'
  BUILD_NUMBER: $(Build.BuildNumber)
```

Then I was able to reference the build number:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</finalName>
```