# MuleSoft Maven plugin not reading variables in Azure pipelines

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mulesoft

I have a MuleSoft application that I am trying to deploy from a pipeline.
I am using a Maven plugin and a connected app for credentials. Plugin configuration looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <armDeployment>
    <muleVersion>${app.runtime}</muleVersion>
    <uri>https://anypoint.mulesoft.com</uri>
    <businessGroupId>${BUSINESSGROUPID}</businessGroupId>
    <target>${TARGET}</target>
    <targetType>${TARGETGROUP}</targetType>
    <connectedAppClientId>${APPCLIENTID}</connectedAppClientId>
    <connectedAppClientSecret>${APPCLIENTSECRET}</connectedAppClientSecret>
    <connectedAppGrantType>client_credentials</connectedAppGrantType>
    <environment>${ENVIRONMENT}</environment>
  </armDeployment>
</configuration>
```

I define variables in Azure pipeline(3 of them are secret credentials) and when I run the pipeline I am getting 401 Unauthorized error.

When I hard-code values in the above configuration it works fine. Only when I try to have the POM file read them from the pipeline variables do I get this error.
Below is my pipeline config too:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  APPCLIENTID: $(APPCLIENTID)
  APPCLIENTSECRET: $(APPCLIENTSECRET)
  ENVIRONMENT: $(ENVIRONMENT)
  BUSINESSGROUPID: $(BUSINESSGROUPID)
  TARGET: $(TARGET)
  TARGETGROUP: $(TARGETGROUP)


pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'clean package deploy -DmuleDeploy'
```

I am not sure whether I need to define variables here again or not.

How do I make the POM file read variables correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure DevOps - how to reference Pipeline variables in pom file's build finalName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62773839/azure-devops-how-to-reference-pipeline-variables-in-pom-files-build-finalname)

Comment: This question is purely related to how to pass Azure pipeline variables as Maven properties. There is nothing Mule or MuleSoft specific in this problem.

Comment: Do you mean I should access the variables like this? ${env.Environment} or ${project.Environment} or something? I am not sure how the guy in the thread you posted solved his issue.

Comment: I see, the example is for the build name and not to use variable inside the pom. I provided a possible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what the issue is.
Azure Pipelines documentation states that you need to use $() in order to access variables but in the case of a POM file you need to use {}. So the POM file should look like this:

```
<configuration>
<armDeployment>
    <muleVersion>${app.runtime}</muleVersion>
    <uri>https://anypoint.mulesoft.com</uri>
    <businessGroupId>${BUSINESSGROUPID}</businessGroupId>
    <target>${TARGET}</target>
    <targetType>${TARGETGROUP}</targetType>
    <connectedAppClientId>${APPCLIENTID}</connectedAppClientId>
    <connectedAppClientSecret>${APPCLIENTSECRET}</connectedAppClientSecret>
    <connectedAppGrantType>client_credentials</connectedAppGrantType>
    <environment>${ENVIRONMENT}</environment>
  </armDeployment>
</configuration>
```

One more thing I noticed is that doing this will not allow POM file to read variables set as secret. I am yet to find out how to make this work properly but for now I got most of it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Azure Pipeline variables directly in the pom. They are not properties in Maven. You have to define them explicitly as such in Maven's command line.

In the goals input you can define Maven properties for the command line and assign them the values from the respective Azure Pipeline variable using the 'goals' input.

I'm guessing that the [syntax for referencing variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) is `$(var)` so as an example:

```
    goals: 'clean package deploy -DmuleDeploy -DAPPCLIENTID=$(APPCLIENTID)'
```

Just try adding the other properties next to APPCLIENTID.

Comment: And how do I access them in the POM file? I have tried `<environment>${ENVIRONMENT}</environment>` and `<environment>${env.ENVIRONMENT}</environment>` but in both cases I get this error `Couldn't find environmentName named [$(ENVIRONMENT)]`. I understand that POM file sees that value as it is and not as a variable?

Comment: You are using Maven properties already as you showed in your question. Example: `    <connectedAppClientId>${APPCLIENTID}</connectedAppClientId>`. I didn't suggest any changes because you already got that part right.